# Rendering Problems - Cannot resolve Symbol '@drawable

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to add imageViews to my device on android and I am receiving this - 
http://gyazo.com/f84e128fd2a5183dd80bacc45d0fcb6d - I am trying to find my images but the src says it's not there but it is there. - http://gyazo.com/8c3b8f7086477458ad9fa538ec701288. Now here is a image of all my images in my drawable - /40b12877a85ad4511028c492ebd49a51. Now here is my whole layout code. Just add the /40b12877a85ad4511028c492ebd49a51 at the end of the gyazo link since my reputation isn't high.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/table">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgdice1"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="141dp"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:onClick="dice1"
        android:src="@drawable/imgdice1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRollDice"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:text="Roll Dice"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</GridLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgdice2"
    android:layout_width="143dp"
    android:layout_height="143dp"
    android:src="@drawable/imgdice1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imgdice1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="73dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does this happen only for this image? Did you try to refresh your project or restart your IDE?

Comment: @HaneloreIanoseck I refreshed my project like rebuilding it and cleaning it. I'll try restarting my IDE.

Answer (score 2):

If the drawables are in place and still the Android Studio shows error, do this:

Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and Invalidate and Restart.

This cleared the errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but I can't see the image imgdice1 in your drawable folder. only table and ic_launcher.

did you copy the imgdice1 image like the table image?

can you show the contents of your drawable folder in windows explorer?